# How Can I Set Permission to Everyone for New File in Shared Folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions, android, shared-folders, google-drive

I had a network with 1 server PC and 7 client PC. File sharing from server to client works well.

Today I installed google drive desktop in server PC because my boss want to working from her tablet PC (with google drive from android).

The problem is, when new file created from her tablet PC and synced to google drive, client PC unable to open those file because file permission is not "Everyone".

How can I set default file permission to "everyone" when server PC's google drive download those file?

Server PC applications:

1. Windows 7
2. Google Drive Desktop

Tablet PC applications:

1. Android Kitkat
2. OfficeSuite 8 + PDF Pro
3. Google Drive for Android